# Finding div left position relative to window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, screen-orientation

I want to find the div left position relative to window.

[image: Sample Page]

I am doing like this

```
 var diff = ($('.content-wrapper').outerWidth(true) - $('.content-wrapper').outerWidth()) ;
```

This is working fine but I want to see if there are any better ways to do it?

Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

```
var left = document.querySelector('div').getBoundingClientRect().left;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

```js
function getOffsetLeft() {
  var testDiv = document.getElementById("test");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = testDiv.getBoundingClientRect().left;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

#test {
  left: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid black
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <p>Click the button to get getBoundingClientRect().leftt for the test div.</p>
  <p><button onclick="getOffsetLeft()">Try it</button></p>
  <p>offsetLeft is: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I need relative to screen

Comment: Try to use `getBoundingClientRect` as Raphael said :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the offset() method

```
var diff = $('.content-wrapper').offset().left - $(window).scrollLeft();
```

Answer (score 0):

only this code is enough

```
$('.content-wrapper').offset().left
```

I have tested using following code

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}    
.content-wrapper{
            position: relative;
            left: 100px;
            width: 200px;   
            height: 200px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

<div style="position:relative; left: 40px; width: 500px;height:auto; border: 1px solid black;">dfgdfgdf
 <div class="content-wrapper">
 dfs sf dsfds fsdfdsf
 </div>
 </div>
```

I am getting left including border of parent.

result is : 141  [ self div left is 100 + parrent div border 1 + parrent div left 40 ]